# Compute HIVE statistics in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to compute HIVE table statistic from Apache Spark:

```
`sqlCtx.sql('ANALYZE TABLE t1 COMPUTE STATISTICS')`
```

I also execute statement to see what was collected:

`sqlCtx.sql('DESC FORMATTED t1')`

I can see my stats was collected.
However when I execute same staement in HIVE client (Ambari) - there are no statistics displayed. Is it available only to Spark if it's collected by Spark? 
Does spark store it somewhere else?

Another question.

I also computing stats for all columns in that table:

`sqlCtx.sql('ANALYZE TABLE t1 COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS c1,c2')`

But when I want to see this stats in spark, it failed with unsupported sql statement exception:

`sqlCtx.sql('DESC FORMATTED t1 c1')`

According to docs it's valid hive queries.
What is wrong with it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Likely because Spark with Hive support enabled is not a Hive client. It is Spark which happens to "know" how to use Hive metastore and how to call Hive functions.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Spark stores statistics as "Table parameters".
To be able retrieve these stats, we need to connect to HIVE metastore and . execute query like following

```
select param_key, param_value 
from table_params tp, tbls t 
where tp.tbl_id=t.tbl_id and tbl_name = '<table_name>' 
and param_key like 'spark.sql.stat%';
```

Comment: I tried this and getting an exception as follows:- `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: table_params`

Comment: The important bit: you need to do it on `HIVE metastore`, not *HIVE*

Answer (score 0):

just uppercase the name of table will be ok.

```sql
select param_key, param_value 
from TABLE_PARAMS tp, TBLS t 
where tp.tbl_id=t.tbl_id and tbl_name = '<table_name>' 
and param_key like 'spark.sql.stat%';
```